# Find the all chain of one to one node in graph

Tags: algorithm, tree, nodes, graph-theory, undirected-graph

I go the un-directed graph `G` an my goal is to find all the possible chains longest than `N`  of nodes in a one to one relation.

For example:

In the the next Graph the "chains" of length more than 2 of nodes in one to one relation are:

```
- d -> e -> f -> g
- c -> k -> l -> m
```

[image]

So what is the best approach or algorithm to solve this problem ?

Comment: Are your graphs always trees?

Comment: Works on all graphs: Iterate over all verticesin no particular order. Mark all visited nodes. Whenever you reach a vertex with degree 2, Start following both edges until the chain ends or you reach a vertex with degree > 2, marking the visited nodes as you go. If the combined length from both searches is <=2, dismiss the result, else add one end vertex to your result set. Continue while there are unvisited nodes. `O(n)`. The degree test on vertices is `O(1)` on adjacency list representations

Comment: @collapsar: never terminates if the graph is a circular list

Comment: @eli.rodriguez Do you want a linear time algorithm and in which algorithm.

Comment: @RobertoAttias Sure it does, as soon as the list has been traversed, there are no more unmarked vertices. Should have been made clearer in my  description, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to find all paths so that each vertex in it has a degree <=2, then the simple approach may be as follows.

Remove all vertices with degree >2 from your graph. You are left with a graph with each vertex having a degree <=2. It is easy to prove that every connected component of such a graph is either a simple way, either a simple loop, and it is easy to distinguish them (for example, running a DFS from one node and seeing whether you ever return to it).

So, every component that is a path is a path you look for. Every component that is a loop is also a path you look for, or can be easily converted to such a path by removing an edge or a vertex, depending on whether you allow a loop as the needed path.

Comment: Wow, is a very simple and effective approach